# Is it normal behavior for local planners to ignore static obstacles if no pointcloud or laserscan data is being published?

Tags: ros, navigation, avoid-obstacle, teb-local-planner, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have tried the following local planners:

1. base_local_planner
2. dwa local planner
3. teb_local_planner

and all of them are ignoring obstacles on a static map, The global planners on the other hand never generate a path that would cause a collision with any obstacle.

It is noteworthy that I am not using kinect or a laser scanner so can't possibly publish pointcloud or laserscan messages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255220/is-it-normal-behavior-for-local-planners-to-ignore-static-obstacles-if-no-pointcloud-or-laserscan-data-is-being-published?/) by [geetam](https://answers.ros.org/users/29435/geetam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not related to the local planners directly but to the local costmap setup (costmap_2d).
Local planners in the navigation stack have only access to the local costmap, so you need to add the desired layer
to the configuration.

Based on the [Robot Setup](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) and [Configure and run Robot Navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials/Configure%20and%20run%20Robot%20Navigation)
Tutorial you might try the following:

E.g. in `local_costmap_params.yaml` (or similar):

```
  rolling_window: true
  width: 5.0
  height: 5.0
  resolution: 0.1

  plugins:
   ## Without proximity sensors, we do not need any obstacle_layer:
   # - {name: obstacle_layer,      type: "costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"}

   ## Static Layer
   - {name: static_layer,            type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
   
   # Uncomment the following line if you want to inflate occupied cells 
   #- {name: inflation_layer,     type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
```

Note, you might add more configurations for layers (inflation_layer and static_layer) either here or in the `costmap_common_params.yaml`. Please check the costmap_2d documentation (*static_map* topic name, service, ...).

Notice, there was an issue early 2015 (see [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/200573/static-layer-on-local-costmap/)) but it seems to be fixed according to the related merge requests on github. If it still does not work,

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2017-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [geetam](https://answers.ros.org/users/29435/geetam/) on 2017-02-21**:
Thanks a lot for replying, The robot gets stuck when I add a static layer (even where there are no obstacles), teb_local_planner repeatedly prints "Trajectory is not feasible", I will read costmap_2d_documentation more carefully and will comment here again if it works.
ROS Version: Indigo.

**Comment by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) on 2017-02-21**:
The teb_local_planer prints this message if a collision with the current robot footprint (also specified in the costmap parameters) is detected. Did you configure the footprint correctly and did you also try dwa_local_planner with the static layer (to check if it is a bug)?

**Comment by [geetam](https://answers.ros.org/users/29435/geetam/) on 2017-02-21**:
I don't think it is a bug in teb_local_planner as robot gets stuck even when dwa is used, value of robot_footprint: [[-0.11, -0.01], [0.11, -0.01], [-0.11, 0.2], [0.11, 0.2] ]
dwa prints warning "off map " with two floating point values. Can I post my yamls here?